# How do I count the number of records in a Cassandra table using the GoCQL driver?

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

I wanted write a simple program in golang (prefer GoCql) to count the number of records in a Cassandra table. so I can reduce the amount  of load on db at a time and reduce the probability of timeouts. I just wanted to count the number of elements with **where** clause.

Please suggest the answers in brief if possible, I'm a complete newbie. It will help me a lot.

Like a query of count number of order of a user with a given userId

```
Select * from KeySpace.OrderTable where userid = userId
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extremely simplified app that counts the number of rows in the `system.local` table for the partition `local` using the GoCQL driver:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocql/gocql"
)

func main() {
    // connect to a Cassandra cluster running locally
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1:9042")
    session, _ := _cluster.CreateSession()

    iter := session.Query(`SELECT COUNT(version) FROM system.local WHERE key = 'local'`).Iter()
    for iter.Scan(&rows) {
        fmt.Printf("%d rows\n", rows)
    }
}
```

Just remember that you should only count rows within a partition. Unbounded queries (not restricted to a partition key) will do a full table scan which is expensive as I've documented in [Why `COUNT()` is bad in Cassandra](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314567/). Cheers!

Comment: If we have a large database. How you can surely say that it can work with very less load on DB servers.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Where did I say "it can work with very less load"? Was that a question for someone else? 

Comment: oh I understand it... Thanks for the brief answer!